# Azure AI search returning different search result for client, demo app and on portal

Tags: .net-core, azure-ai, azure-ai-search

I have created AI Search service on Azure, added index, indexers, semantic ranker and so on. Search generally works but it's returning completely different results for each of the clients...

C# client (nuget package, latest)

```
var searchClient = new SearchClient(new Uri(SearchEndpoint), indexName, new AzureKeyCredential(SearchApiKey));

var options = new SearchOptions();

options.IncludeTotalCount = true;
options.SemanticSearch = new Azure.Search.Documents.Models.SemanticSearchOptions() 
{ 
    SemanticConfigurationName = SearchSemanticRanker
};
options.VectorSearch = null;
```

Demo app payload:

```
{"count":true,"skip":0,"top":50,"searchMode":"any","queryType":"simple","facets":["ImageLink,count:5,sort:count","RegularPrice,count:5,sort:count","Color,count:5,sort:count","Size,count:5,sort:count","BusinessName,count:5,sort:count","Status,values:0|1000000","ProductCategoryName,count:5,sort:count","Currency,count:5,sort:count","Price,count:5,sort:count","IdProduct,count:5,sort:count","ProductURL,count:5,sort:count"],"search":"hd tv 40\" android"}
```

Search query on Azure portal (Search Explorer):

```
{
  "search": "hd tv 40\" android",
  "semanticConfiguration": "products-hr-semantic-ranker"
}
```

All three of them return different results, Azure portal being closest to optimal, demo app 2nd and C# client having worst result. They all point to same index and C# client and Azure use same semantic ranker.

[edit] - I've tried setting this

```
options.QueryType = Azure.Search.Documents.Models.SearchQueryType.Simple;
options.SearchMode = Azure.Search.Documents.Models.SearchMode.Any;
```

to the search options to match demo client but there is no change and also if I understand correctly, those are default values anyway.

Why are the results that different?